# Cancelling one (or several) certain ASIHTTPRequests in an ASINetworkQueue

Tags: iphone, ipad, asihttprequest, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

In my iPhone/iPad app I'm handling all network and web-API-requests through a "APIManager" (singleton, created in AppDelegate).

Currently the APIManager contains only one single ASINetworkQueue, to which APIRequests (subclass of ASIHTTPRequest) are added and executed. In the userInfo of each APIRequest some additional information to handle the request is added (like whether the response should be parsed into Core Data - and if so, which entity - or not).

When the user moves from one view (ViewA) to another (ViewX), I would like to have the possibility to cancel all the requests that ViewA have asked the APIManager to perform, while letting others continue.

Is there some functionality to find a certain request in a ASINetworkQueue (or NSOperationQueue) and send a cancellation message to it? Maybe using parameters added to the userInfo of the request?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[queue operations]` will return an NSArray of items in the queue, which you can then iterate and call 'cancel' on any you like.

Something like:

```
for (ASIHTTPRequest *req in [queue operations])
{
    if (shouldCancel(req))
        [req cancel];
}
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! I'll try it out later today, thanks!